# What should be the return type of following method?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
class A {}

class B extends A{}

class C extends B{}

public class Test {
   public List<? extends B> ring(){
     return ???
   }
}
```

Please tell me, which of the below can be legal return type of the method ring()?

```
return new ArrayList<B>();
return new ArrayList<C>();
return new ArrayList<A>();
return new ArrayList<? extends B>();
return new LinkedList<B>();
return new PriorityQueue<B>();
return new ArrayList();
```

Comment: yes..but for learning purpose, and don't you think that this is little bit difficult "homework"?Please let me know if you have some idea.

Comment: whatever you do, do not open an editor and try this yourself.  it may indeed trigger the big crunch

Comment: Difficult?  No.  If yes, time to learn another language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning `List<? extends B>` so find you valid option below:

1. `return new ArrayList<B>();` **valid:** because any class is a sub and super class of it self
2. `return new ArrayList<C>();`  **valid:** because `C` is extending `B`
3. `return new ArrayList<A>();`  **invalid:** because `A` is not extending `B`
4. `return new LinkedList<B>();`  **valid:** because `List` is super class of `LinkedList`
5. `return new PriorityQueue<B>();` **invalid:** because  `PriorityQueue` is not a List.
6. `return new ArrayList();` **valid:** with warning .

Answer (score 0):

You should really ask "What are the valid return statements?" Most of these work.  The ones that don't are:

- return new ArrayList();  // An ArrayList is a List, but A does not extend B.
- return new ArrayList(); // You can never instantiate a wildcarded generic. You can declare one, but you don't create one yourself.
- return new PriorityQueue(); // A PriorityQueue is not a List.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to return a List of B, the first and second ones are allowed.

The third one is not, because it's not true that A IS-A B; A does not extend B.

Fourth one makes no sense to me.

Fifth one is fine, because LinkedList IS-A List.

Sixth one doesn't work, because PriorityQueue doesn't implement List.

Seventh one is okay, but the compiler might warn you.  It's less type safe, and that's the point of generics.